# How does conditional formating work with Regex? I.E. if there is a blacksplash present ensure it is follow by one of the following { bnrt'' }

Tags: regex

I am new to regex so I do not have all the terminology down, but I am trying to write a regex for string literals. All characters are allowed including some escape characters. Additionally, the string should begin and end with a quotation mark.

I have tried

```
(^\")(?=.*\\)(b|n|r|t).*($")
```

I think I am using the ? incorrectly, my thought process is if there is a backsplash, it should be followed by one of those characters, then any other remaining characters in the string literal.

Is there a way to create conditional formatting where if one character is present, it must be followed by one character from a list? i.e if the backsplash is present, it must be followed by one of these, bnrt'"\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might exclude the backslash and `"` from matching, and only match the backslash when it is preceding any of `[bnrt]` using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
^"[^"\\]*(?:\\[bnrt][^"\\]*)*"$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `"` Match `"` at the start
- `[^"\\]*` Match 0+ times any char except `"` and `\\`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\\[bnrt]` Match `\\` and either `b` `n` `r` `t`
  - `[^"\\]*` Match 0+ times any char except `"` and `\\`
- `)*` Close non capture group
- `"` Match `"` at the end
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C64Opy/1)